# How to access innerhtml from a directive after template interpolation

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have a directive like this called ellipsis. I use it like this:

```
<p class="card-text" ellipsis>{{ description }}</p>
```

And here is the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ellipsis]'
})
export class EllipsisDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer2) {
        console.log(el);
    }

    truncateText() {
        let el = this.el.nativeElement;
        var wordArray = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
        while(el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
            wordArray.pop();
            el.innerHTML = wordArray.join(' ') + '...';
        }
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        this.truncateText();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `innerHTML` is empty. But the original `{{ description }}` is NOT. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not make it so you pass the content to the directive, `[ellipsis]="description"`?

Comment: Thanks but is there no way to access the content of the element after the interpolation?

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` should help you

Answer (score 0):

It's not very intuitive but `ngAfterViewChecked` seems to work. I tried all the events.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.truncateText();
}
```